# Pgpromise Queries are exectuting without waiting on batch

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I'm working with pgpromise to batch my insert queries however they are executed without waiting on the batch transaction batch.

```
    db.tx((t) => {
      const insertQueries = [];

      queryInfo.forEach((info) => {
        insertQueries.push(
          t.none(
            `INSERT INTO test 
            (name) 
            VALUES  
            ('test')`,
            []
          )
        );
      });
      // return t.batch(insertQueries);
    });
```

Note that t.batch is commented out. I would therefore (possibly erronously) expect for the queries to not get executed. However the database is showing the inserted rows. If this is not the case, how can I ensure that all the transaction are actually executed how I expect them to?

[image: screenshot of test table results]

Comment: `t.none()` runs them, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`batch` is a legacy API, created before `await/async` syntax became widely supported.

```js
await db.tx(async t => {
    for (let a in info) {
        await t.none('INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES($1)', ['test']);
    }
});
```

> I would therefore (possibly erronously) expect for the queries to not get executed

You do execute queries by calling `t.one`. Method `batch` simply settles all the promises returned from it. If you want to stop producing queries when one of them errors, the above `async/await` approach is better.

Comment: my goal is for the all  "t.none" calls to be part of the same transaction. I.e if one of them fails the commit to rest of them is denied. Is there a way to accomplish this with pg-promise?

Comment: @insivika The code in this answer does that.